# Can we solve equations for a sum of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am wondering if there is a way to solve the following.
Suppose we have

$$\sum_{n=r}^{\infty} f(n) = a(r).$$

Can I solve this for $f$ if I know the expression for $a$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know $a(r)$, then you have $f(r)=a(r)-a(r+1)$.  Sometimes you can use this to get a nice formula for $f(r)$